# Partial integration for Riemann–Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

For $u,v: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $v$ is integrable with respect to $u$ and $u$ with respect to $v$.

I have to show the following two rules for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals:

1. $\int_a^b 1 dv(t)=v(b)-v(a)$
2. $\int_a^budv(t)+vdu(t)=\int_a^b 1d(uv)(t)=u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a)$

My problem is:

1) I cannot find a reference with a proof of the partial integration for RS-Integrals.

2) Dont see how to use this for the above

Any help?

Comment: This is standard result in the theory of Riemann Stieltjes integration. You can look for the proof in *Mathematical Analysis* by Tom M. Apostol.

Comment: You can also observe that the first result is trivial in the sense that it is an immediate consequence of the definition of Riemann Stieltjes integral.